# JSP include not working as expected

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to include a dynamic jsp inside another jsp.

Supposedly the output of the included jsp should appear within the parent jsp and I've tried this in other projects and works flawlessly. But in this case when the parent jsp is called the only output I get is the one from the included jsp

```
<form:form>
 ...form databinding...
</form:form>

<jsp:include page="data.jsp" />
```

The project runs on spring MVC and this view has some model attributes ready to print and bind and from what I've read this shouldn't cause any trouble

What am I missing?

Comment: Is there anything else in the "parent" JSP? If not, add something like an `<h1>` as a sanity check. Also check the logs.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, there's the form with the <form:input> fields and some jstl {obj.prop}. Tried the <h1>, if I remove the include the form renders normally but if I add it the included jsp overrides the parent

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `<%@include file="data.jsp"%>`. This directive includes the file before the JSP is translated into a servlet class, so both files are seen as one class on execution. If I understand correctly, the `<jsp:include>` action includes the file when the class is executed and only the output of the included file is included in the enclosing JSP, hence the issue.

I just tried a test using `<%@include%>` with a spring form in the included file and it worked fine for me.

Comment: That's incorrect, the <jsp:include> tag should not be replacing the original output. A static include is a different beast and may or may not be what's actually required.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, now the page is completely blank. I'm sure there's something missing but right now I don't know what maybe it's an issue with sitemesh. I'll keep looking into it for a while, thanks tough.